# How to add a string before a query return in prisma?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, multer, prisma

I have a backend that uses NestJS and Prisma for the DB. I have an attachments model that holds the location of files. Currently I save the files with the entire route needed for pulling it back out like so `'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/123.jpg'`. I want to save it as `'/123.jpg'` and have prisma add the domain string in front `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api` so the server can be easily moved to different domains.

I have a for loop that goes through the queries and adds the domain as I want, but I have to do this for every association and route in my site. Do you all know a good way for prisma to handle this as the query is performed?

schema.prisma

```
model Attachment {
  id                        Int                   @id @default(autoincrement())
  //is there a way to inject a domain url string in front of the string this sends out?
  thumbnail                 String?
  original                  String?
}
```

**Solved**

I put [@ConnorFogarty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74426282/18244921) into /prisma/prisma.ts as shown below:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { APP_URL } from '../src/common/constants';

let prisma: PrismaClient;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

//middleware to add server link to all requests for Attachments with original/thumbnail
prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
  console.log('params', params)
  if (params.model == 'Attachment' && params.action == 'findMany') {
    params.args.data.thumbnail = APP_URL + params.args.data.thumbnail;
  }

  return next(params)
})

export default prisma;
```

In my console you can see params is missing params.args.data

```
params {
  args: { include: { avatar: true, addresses: true } },
  dataPath: [],
  runInTransaction: false,
  action: 'findMany',
  model: 'User'
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, that you will receive thumbnail name like "'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/123.jpg'" ?

Comment: My front end NextJS requires the DB to send the entire URL for the file locaitons, but when you deploy to different servers you need to change the URL to match the domain so instead of saving the entire URL to the DB I save the relative location and use a .env variable to load the server URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prisma [middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) allows you to run code before or after a query. In your case, you can define a middleware method for `findMany` (or whatever other queries you run) that inserts the server url before the attachment path:

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
    const server = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/";

    if (params.model === "Attachment" && params.action === "findMany") {
      // run findMany query
      const result = await next(params);

      // prepend server to thumbnail
      const modified = result.map((res) => ({
        ...res,
        thumbnail: server + res.thumbnail,
      }));

      return modified;
    }

    return next(params);
});
```

Comment: I am not sure where I should add this. I added it to the prisma folder that has the prisma.service and schema.prisma files and it did not help. I also tried my service file where my query is made. I am still new to prisma so sorry is this is a dumb question.

Comment: No worries -- add it where you create your Prisma client (`const prisma = new PrismaClient()`)

Comment: I gave you the answer vote. However I do not see the data in params.args.data. I put an edit in the original question to show a <code>console.log(params</code> in and it doesn't have the data piece. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my original response. I've edited the code and tested it on an existing Next.js + Prisma project. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: That worked great! I had to change the === to == to get it to compile. It said the if statement would never fire because there is no overlap in those types Now I just need to figure out how to get it to work when Attachments is associated to another model like User which associates to Attachments via avatar.

Comment: Ah that's probably because the value I checked against `params.model` was for my prisma schema instead of yours. I changed the string to `Attachment` which should work with `===` now.